# how to find if the song is ended in android

Tags: android

i use MediaPlayer in android and i am playing a song by start method and **i have to find if the song is ended not paused or stop.** . please help me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please implement onCompletion Listener .

```
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
```

When song is ended then media player automatically called onCompletion method.

```
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) 
{
    // Write your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to register [OnCompletionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html) using [setOnCompletionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnCompletionListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener%29) method. When the song is played [endCompletion](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html#onCompletion%28android.media.MediaPlayer%29) will be called.